# form field validation

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to validate some user information field in a form. For example, there are  first name, last name, address,  there should be an alert info if user doesn't fill it out comletely.  Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Implement [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) interface.